# optimization google script - accessing 25 spreadsheets

Tags: optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on some spreadsheets (25 of them), every one of them is for one employee and has 12 sheets, one for month. Sometimes, alas, all spreadsheets need some changes. Now they need some changes on formatting. And the script below works. But it is very slow. **Can you help me with optimization?** I think the main field of optimization should be jumping to specific cells to make the borders. I have no idea what can I do to make it faster.

The second thing about optimization is that this script works for 4 spreadsheets – if I give all 25 spreadsheets at once it finishes in the middle of 5th.

```
 function format() {

//list of spreadsheetIDs, I have 25 of them, each one is a summary for one employee
var summary = [
'example1_asdfghjklqwertyuiop',
'example2_asdfghjklqwertyuiop’,
……
……
……
'example24_asdfghjklqwertyuiop’,
'example25_asdfghjklqwertyuiop’
];

//list of sheets in every spreadsheet, they are the same in everyone spreadsheet, month names are here in Polish
var month= ['Styczeń','Luty','Marzec','Kwiecień','Maj','Czerwiec','Lipiec','Sierpień','Wrzesień','Październik','Listopad','Grudzień'];

     for each (ss in summary){
     var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss);
          for each (m in month){
          var sheet = s.getSheetByName(m);
              if (m == 'Styczeń'||m == 'Marzec'||m == 'Maj'||m == 'Lipiec'||m == 'Sierpień'||m == 'Październik'||m == 'Grudzień'){
                   var days = 31; 
              } else if (m == 'Kwiecień'||m == 'Czerwiec'||m == 'Wrzesień'||m == 'Listopad'){
                   days = 30;
              } else {
                   days = 28;
              };

       sheet.getRangeList(['F11:F43', 'K11:K43', 'M11:M43', 'U11:U43', 'AA11:AA43']).setFontColor('#999999');
          for (var i = 1 ; i<=days ; i++){
          //13 row is the first row for 1st January, February…
var cell = sheet.getRange(12 + i, 7);
          //checking if background color of a cell is white (holidays, saturdays and sundays have different backgroung)
         var bg_color = sheet.getRange(12 + i, 7).getBackground();
             if (bg_color == "#ffffff") {
//if a day is weekday then its row needs to have some cells with border
             sheet.getRange(12 + i,  7).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
             sheet.getRange(12 + i, 12).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
             sheet.getRange(12 + i, 14).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
             sheet.getRange(12 + i, 21).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
             sheet.getRange(12 + i, 27).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
             //sheet.getRange('A1:AE50').setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
             }
          }
       }
     }
}
```

Comment: Use a rangelist to apply common border stylings, and use a "dispatcher" object to remove your if-else chain for setting days (e.g. `dayLookup = { "January": 31, "February": 28, ...}; var day = dayLookup[m];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two sources of optimizations to be made without significantly changing your workflow. The first is very minor, and removes an `if-else` chain:

```
if (m == 'Styczeń'||m == 'Marzec'||m == 'Maj'||m == 'Lipiec'||m == 'Sierpień'||m == 'Październik'||m == 'Grudzień'){
  var days = 31; 
} else if (m == 'Kwiecień'||m == 'Czerwiec'||m == 'Wrzesień'||m == 'Listopad'){
  days = 30;
} else {
  days = 28;
};
```

becomes

```
var daysFromMonth = {
  'Styczen': 31,
  'Marzec': 31,
  'Maj': 31,
   ...
  'Kwiecien': 30,
   ...
};
```

and is moved outside of your loop over spreadsheet IDs. Then, inside your loop, you use it as:

```js
var days = daysFromMonth[m] || 28;
```

The `|| 28` will handle all cases where the value returned by accessing the property whose name is contained in `m` is "falsy" (0, false, null, undefined, ''), corresponding to your `else` condition.

The major improvement to make is to use batch methods per the Apps Script best practices. You use one batch method (`RangeList#setFontColor`) already, and just need to perform a batch read (turning `Range#getBackground` into `Range#getBackgrounds`) and more batch writes (using `RangeList#setBorder` instead of `Range#setBorder`):

Inside your loop over spreadsheets, after you obtain the number of days and set the font color:

```js
...
sheet.getRangeList(['F11:.......]).setFontColor('#999999');
var start = { row: 13, col: 7 };
var backgrounds = sheet.getRange(start.row, start.col, days, 1).getBackgrounds(); // read all backgrounds at once
```

Now you can look at all the background colors and identify which addresses to format using pure JS, instead of repeatedly calling the Spreadsheet Service (very slow) in between your JS (very fast).

```js
var rgToBorderize = [];
var colsToInclude = [7, 12, 14, 21, 27];
backgrounds.forEach(function (bgColor, idx) { // idx is 0-based
  if (bgColor === '#ffffff') {
    colsToInclude.forEach(function (col) {
      rgToBorderize.push('R' + (start.row + idx) + 'C' + col);
    });
  }
});
sheet.getRangeList(rgToBorderize).setBorder(/** your border spec here */);
```

Some references:

- [Apps Script "Best Practices"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)
- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Don't use `for each (var ... in ... )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)
- [class `RangeList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)